# Qt stylesheet selector using enumed properties

Tags: qt, enums, css-selectors, qtstylesheets

I'm trying to set different visual styles for a pressed `QToolButton` depending on whether it displays a menu or not.

In my code, tool buttons having menu set their `popupMode` property to `QToolButton::InstantPopup` (value 2), while buttons without an associated menu keep the default value (`QToolButton::DelayedPopup`, value 0).

I tried to use such property in different ways as selector, but only the last one (`QToolButton[popupMode="2"]`) worked:

```
/* Not working */
QToolButton[popupMode=InstantPopup]:pressed,
QToolButton[popupMode="InstantPopup"]:pressed,
QToolButton[popupMode="QToolButton::InstantPopup"]:pressed,
QToolButton[popupMode="QToolButton--InstantPopup"]:pressed,
QToolButton[qproperty-popupMode=InstantPopup]:pressed,
QToolButton[qproperty-popupMode="InstantPopup"]:pressed,
QToolButton[qproperty-popupMode="QToolButton::InstantPopup"]:pressed,
QToolButton[qproperty-popupMode="QToolButton--InstantPopup"]:pressed,
QToolButton[qproperty-popupMode="2"]:pressed
{
    background-color: blue;
}
/* Working */
QToolButton[popupMode="2"]:pressed,
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

(This is a compilation of the options, I've tested them separately).

[Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#setting-qobject-properties) mentions that if the enum is declared using `Q_ENUM` (as `ToolButtonPopupMode` does), then it should be referenced by name, not by value, but, as it can be seen above, it seems it is not the case for selectors.

---

**Question:** Would it be possible to use such enum's name as selector in the stylesheet instead of the enum's value?

---

*Note: I understand that other options such as custom properties with a more expressive, Qt-independant value can make the work too. I'm curious about the possibility of using the enum in the described way.*

Answer (score 0):

`QToolButton[popupMode=InstantPopup]:pressed` is the correct one.

`setProperty(<property_name>, QVariant::fromValue(<enum_value>))` for enum class.

`setProperty(<property_name>, <enum_value>)` for enum.

But you need to reload the style if you want it to change dynamically.
Read about `QStyle::unpolish` and `QStyle::polish`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it seems there is some information missing to make it work correctly. I've made several tries like setting the property manually using `setProperty` (though I think it'd complicate the solution, but I've tried anyway), unpolishing / polishing after creation, when the button is pressed, when the associated menu is about to show, and nothing works. May you please add more details in how to get it? Thanks for your time!